# fetch data from url and show this in log console in php

Tags: php, urlfetch

I want to fetch data from https://aloostad.com/api/PodcastCourse?Page=1 and show data items in the console but PHP gives me an error.

```
<?php
// $response = file_get_contents('https://aloostad.com/api/PodcastCourse');
// $response = json_decode($response);
// // $response = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
// echo "<script>console.log(" . $response . " );</script>";

$url = "https://aloostad.com/api/PodcastCourse?Page=1";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$output = [];
parse_str($parts['query'], $output);
// echo $output['page'];
echo "<script>console.log('" . $output['page'] . "');</script>";
?>
```

This site has Swagger at the URL
https://aloostad.com/swagger/index.html

The error is

```
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\mamad.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://aloostad.com/api/PodcastCourse?Page=1";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$output = [];
parse_str($parts['query'], $output);
echo $output['Page'];
```

Comment: Your code will lead to the same error (Undefined index: page)

Comment: @MeysamSalimi now you got ur problem fixed, do you know y this worked ???

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you use the wrong keyname!

```php
$url = "https://aloostad.com/api/PodcastCourse?Page=1";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$output = [];
parse_str($parts['query'], $output);
var_dump($output);
// array(1) {
//   ["Page"]=>
//   string(1) "1"
// }
```

Use `$output['Page']`, then you should get your value.